# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker switching to today on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

**Background**

I'm adding a date, with Angular UI Bootstrap support, similar like I have implemented in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2LkwT05PKPTDI4x9VyOV?p=preview). The Plunk does exactly what I want it to do.

However, on my local attempt, the selected date switches to `today`, rather than the date set in `ng-model`.

**Local code**

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
            ng-model="person.DateOfBirth"
            is-open="stats.DateOfBirthOpened" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatepicker($event)">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Script:

```
$scope.format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

$scope.stats = {
    DateOfBirthOpened: false
};

$scope.openDatepicker = function ($event) {
    $scope.stats.DateOfBirthOpened = true;
};
```

**Plunk code**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
            ng-model="today" 
            is-open="status.opened" 
            min-date="minDate" 
            max-date="maxDate" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
     </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.status = {
    opened: false
};

$scope.open = function ($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
};

$scope.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";
```

**Question**

As far as I can tell both implementations are very similar *(identical ignoring semantical differences)*, so why is the local code not working correctly (displaying today on open rather than ng-model value)?

**Addendum**

Full controller javascript code as requested:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("controllers.mainControllers")
    .controller("personDetailController", [
        "$scope",
        function ($scope) {
            var self = {};

            self.Get = function () {
                if (coreUtilityService.IsValid($rootScope.PersoonId)) {
                    apiService.Get("api/person/" + $rootScope.PersoonId).then(function (person) {
                        $scope.person = person;
                        $scope.title = coreUtilityService.CombineTwoValuesWithSpace(person.Firstname, person.Lastname);
                    });
                };
            }

            // === $SCOPED === //

            self.Get();

            $scope.format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

            $scope.stats = {
                DateOfBirthOpened: false
            };

            $scope.openDatepicker = function ($event) {
                $scope.stats.DateOfBirthOpened = true;
            };
        }]);
```

And $scope.person output:

```
{PersonId: "9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482", Firstname: "Jackie", Lastname: "Chan", DateOfBirth: "1968-05-17T00:00:00", CreateDate: "2015-12-11T09:15:49.403"…}
CreateDate: "2015-12-11T09:15:49.403"
DateOfBirth: "1968-05-17T00:00:00"
Firstname: "Jackie"
Lastname: "Chan"
ModifyDate: "2015-12-11T09:15:49.403"
PersonId: "9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482"
```

Comment: can you please share full javascript file code

Comment: Done, doesn't add much more though I think.

Comment: i think you haven't defined the value of model which you want to have display in the front.

Comment: It's `person.DateOfBirth`, read from `$scope.person` loaded in the above `self.Get()` function.

Comment: can you just try it once by declaring it static like this `$scope.person = {
      DateOfBirth: new Date("10/30/2010")
    };` instead of getting it from `self.Get()`

Comment: No difference sadly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100560/discussion-between-kunal-kakkad-and-spikee).

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but your promise does resolve and sets $scope.person? I forked your plunk (http://plnkr.co/edit/jFeWYQRVTRHHzYY3P28i?p=preview) and cannot reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The date format in your plunk is wrong use `"{{dd/MM/yyyy}}"` instead of `"{{dd/mm/yyyy}}"`.

**EDIT:** Also the plunk example does not bind the format correctly. Change `{{format}}` to `{{dateFormat}}`.

Comment: I noticed that, if I use `mm` instead of `MM` locally, I get a `00` value for month. I don't know why it's no problem for the Plunk. Both use `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js`.

Comment: What does the returned person object look like?